# I want to fetch data of foreign key's table using laravel

Tags: laravel

i have two tables "Orders" and "users" where id of Users table is foreign key in "Orders" table. i want to fetch data of "Users" table using "Orders" table.

```html
@foreach($orders as $ord)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$ord->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->productname}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->totalprice}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->quantity}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->users->name}}</td>
                          <tr>
 @endforeach
```

so that i want name of user using `{{$ord->users->name}}` query, but
i got error =

> Undefined property: stdClass::$users

Comment: Have you defined relationship in model?

Comment: not defined. But problem is solved after defining it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Order Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and in controller where you pass the value of orders,

```
$order=Order::with('user')->where(your_condition)->get();
```

then access the value in blade

```
@foreach($orders as $ord)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$ord->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->productname}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->totalprice}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->quantity}}</td>
                            <td>{{$ord->user->name}}</td>
                          <tr>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

If you say that you have a `user_id` within your `orders` table. Then in your `Order` model add this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And in the view you can use it like so:

```
{{ $order->user->name }}
```